# Not able to read XML file after exporting Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I have the following directory structure in my eclipse plug-in:

```
> samplePlugin
     > src
     > icons
     > resources
        > db.xml
```

Folder named "resources" was manually created in the samplePlugin project. When i export the plugin as jar file and put it in plugins folder of eclipse root directory and run the plugin in my eclipse, I am not able to read the db.xml file. Please see the below code.

```
 File file = new File("resources/db.xml");  //this line throws file not found exception error

 if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
```

How can i read the xml file after exporting my plugin as jar and run it in eclipse. I tried using Bundle and URL it didn't work out.

Comment: Objects in a plugin jar are not files so you can't use `File`. Look at [Reading resources from a Eclipse plugin](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/)

Comment: @greg-449 - I have a doubt, i created the folder "resources" and created a new xml file in it. When, I export my plugin into jar and extract the jar. I do not see any folder named "resources". Could you let me know why.

Comment: In your plugin.xml editor `Build` tab have you checked the `resources` folder in the `Binary Build` section? That will add an entry to `build.properties` and should include it in the jar.

Comment: @NickWilson.. Its working. Thank you for the suggestion. Could you please let me know why i would need to select it in Binary Build?

Comment: Binary Build is the normal plugin build, everything you want in the plugin must be included (Source Build is for when you ask for the plugin source to be included)